# The function is not applied correctly, and the file is not created properly

Tags: python

```
from hanspell import spell_checker
import csv

with open('test 1st.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
underinput = file.readlines()

input = []
for i in underinput:
temp = i.replace('.','.#').split('#')
input.append(temp)

input_list = [""]

for i in input:
print(i)
if len(input_list[-1]) + len(i) < 500:
    input_list[-1] += i
else:
    input_list.append(i)

result = spell_checker.check(input_list)
memo = [result[0].result]
**file = open('hello.txt', 'w')
file.write(memo)
file.close()**
```

There are many Korean characters in that file. And I want to spellcheck it and make a conclusion file. But there were several errors forward to me.

Error message like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be because `spell_checker.check` returns a tuple of

```
result (Bool, True if the input has been checked),
original (String, The original string)
errors (Number, The number of errors in the input)
words (Dictionary, List of words with their error count)
time (Float, Time taken to complete)
```

your file should be written once you have parsed this data, or cast elements of it to a string.